# The Fourier transform of $p(r)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, improper-integrals, fourier-transform

We are given the function $p(r)$ as:
$$p(r)=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2i}k(S(k)-1)e^{ikr}dk$$

with $S(k)$ being an even function. What is the Fourier transform $P(k)$ of $p(r)$?

I have no idea how to deal with this complicated computation. Is there some help?

Comment: Note that $p(r)$ is given as the inverse Fourier transform of another function, so you don’t actually have to do too much.

Comment: Which convention are you using for the Fourier transform and its inverse?

Answer (score 1):

There is no special technique in that case; by applying the definition of Fourier transform, we get :
$$
\begin{array}{rcl}
P(k) 
   &=& \displaystyle
   \int_\mathbb{R} p(r)e^{-ikr} \,\mathrm{d}r \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   \frac{1}{2i} \int_\mathbb{R}\mathrm{d}r \int_\mathbb{R}\mathrm{d}k' \;k'(S(k')-1)e^{i(k'-k)r} \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   -i\pi \int_\mathbb{R}\mathrm{d}k' \;k'(S(k')-1)\delta(k'-k) \\
   &=& \displaystyle
   -i\pi k(S(k)-1)
\end{array}
$$
where we used the integral representation of the Dirac delta function, namely $\displaystyle \delta(k) = \int_\mathbb{R} \frac{\mathrm{d}r}{2\pi} \,e^{\pm ikr}$.